# How can I use sed to perform this replacement?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to replace a line in file with something

```
#Banner none
```

to

```
Banner /etc/motd
```

I tried:

```
sed -i "s/^#Banner none/Banner /etc/motd/" /root/testfile.sh
```

which is not working. Do you know how I can do what I want?

Comment: @Cyrus: The answer was accepted less than an hour after it was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have slashes in the replacement, you should use other separators than slashes, e.g. commas:

```
sed -i "s,^#Banner none,Banner /etc/motd/," /root/testfile.sh
```

Otherwise, you'd have to escape the slashes in the path:

```
sed -i "s/^#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/motd/"
```

Comment: Or you can use slashes and then use backslashes to escape any slashes in the substitution: `sed -i "s/^#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/motd\//" /root/testfile.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape your slash or use a different separator than "/".

Could use

`sed -i "s/^#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/motd/" /root/testfile.sh`

or

`sed -i "s,^#Banner none,Banner /etc/motd," /root/testfile.sh`